# How to download image file on anchor tag click without opening image in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have following code as below in html file that uses asp.net. If the file is any other than the image file, it downloads automatically. But if the file is image, it opens it in tab and then we have to manually download it. How can I automate this process without prompting user to do so manually? And the values of URL and Filename come from database.

```
<a href="${URL}" download="${FileName}">
   <img 
      src="../Images/Download.png" 
      title="Click here to download the attachment." 
    />
</a>
```

Comment: i don't see an issue with this. if you have correct `href="path/to/image"` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2 shows an example

Comment: Make sure that the image doesn't have a `Content-Disposition: inline` header (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes in the "notes" section).

Answer (score 1):

To download an image, use this syntax:

```
<a href="${Filename}" download="download">
```

Comment: why forcing the name of the file =download? thats not what OP is asking for.

Comment: The OP is already using the `download` attribute. This answer doesn't relate to the question being asked.

Comment: I cannot give the name of the file in href as it will not know where to go to download the file.

Comment: this is not working, its opening image